# How to get context vnode in vue 3 directives

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pug, vuejs3

Сan't get context from directive

```
<template lang="pug">
    div(class="form")
        select(name="name" v-model="form.input" v-select="form.inputs")
            option(v-for="(option, key) in data" :value="key")
                | {{values[key].value}}
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: []
            }
        },
        directives: {
            select: {
                mounted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
                    console.log(vnode.context); // return undefined
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

vnode.context - return **undefined**

vnode.appContext - return **null**

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: []
            }
        },
        directives: {
            select: {
                mounted: function(el, binding) {
                    console.log(binding.instance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).